# What's the fastest way to vectorise creation of combinatorial DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, vectorization, profiling

How can I create the `master` DataFrame through some vectorised process? If it's not possible, what's the most time efficient (not concerned about memory) method to execute this operation?

Can the for-loop be replaced for something more efficient?

As you can see, `combinations` very quickly produces very large number, thus I need a fast way to produce this DataFrame.

Please see below a minimum reproducible example:

```
%%time

import pandas as pd
import string
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations

# create dummy data
cols = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
dummy = pd.DataFrame()
for col in cols:
    dummy = dummy.append([[col, 0] + np.random.randint(2, 100, size=(1, 10)).tolist()[0]])
    dummy = dummy.append([[col, 1] + np.random.randint(2, 100, size=(1, 10)).tolist()[0]])
    dummy = dummy.append([[col, 2] + np.random.randint(2, 100, size=(1, 10)).tolist()[0]])
dummy.columns=['name', 'id', 'v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4', 'v5', 'v1', 'v6', 'v7', 'v8', 'v9']

# create all possible unique combinations
combos = list(combinations(cols, 2))

# generate DataFrame with all combinations
master = pd.DataFrame()
for i, combo in enumerate(combos):
    A = dummy[dummy.name == combo[0]]
    B = dummy[dummy.name == combo[1]]
    joined = pd.merge(A, B, on=["id"], suffixes=('_A', '_B'))
    joined = joined.sort_values("id")
    joined['pair_id'] = i
    master = pd.concat([master, joined])
```

Output:

```
CPU times: total: 1.8 s
Wall time: 1.8 s
```

Thanks!

Comment: Kindly provide sth small with an expected output. From there we can test on scale

Comment: Can you please be more precise?

Comment: Post a small data as text, post the expected output dataframe as text too. Visuals of what you have and what you want to achieve. We can then test solutions for larger data size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your data is structural, you can drop down to numpy to take advantage of vectorized operations.

```py
names = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
ids = [0, 1, 2]
columns = pd.Series(["v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5", "v1", "v6", "v7", "v8", "v9"])

# Generate the random data
data = np.random.randint(2, 100, (len(names), len(ids), len(columns)))

# Pair data for every 2-combination of names
arr = [np.hstack([data[i], data[j]]) for i,j in combinations(range(len(names)), 2)]

# Assembling the data to final dataframe
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
    (p,a,b,i) for p, (a, b) in enumerate(combinations(names,2)) for i in ids
], names=["pair_id", "name_A", "name_B", "id"])
cols = pd.concat([columns + "_A", columns + "_B"])

master = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack(arr), index=idx, columns=cols)
```

Original code: 4s. New code: 7ms

Comment: This is significantly faster, on my machine original is 24.5 ms per loop whereas yours is 0.0571ms which is a 42,807% speed increase! I will approve once tested.

Comment: I've approved your solution, many thanks. When you say data is structural, are you referring to the fact we can reference it more efficiently using `MultiIndex`?

Comment: I meant your data was generated in a very organized way: same shape for each name, then paired up in a consistent manner. It is this structure that allowed us to reduce the problem to aligning numpy arrays for significant speed-up